# Return ordered combinations of letters

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to write a function that returns:

```
['cat', 'cot', 'cut']
```

When passed this list:

```
['c', 'aou', 't']
```

But would also return:

```
['cats', 'catz', 'cots', 'cotz', 'cuts', 'cutz']
```

When passed:

```
['c', 'aou', 't', 'sz']
```

Comment: How is it going, did you run into problems? How can we help? What is the logic behind this function?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? if so please post your code